# ggplot2: fill color behaviour of geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am trying to colour ribbons in ggplot2. When using geom_ribbon, I am able to specify ymin and ymax and a fill color. What it now does is coloring everything that is between ymin and ymax with no regard to upper Limit or lower Limit.

Example (modified from Internet):

```
library("ggplot2")
# Generate data (level2 == level1)
huron <- data.frame(year = 1875:1972, level = as.vector(LakeHuron), level2 = as.vector(LakeHuron))

# Change Level2
huron[1:50,2] <- huron[1:50,2]+100
huron[50:90,2] <- huron[50:90,2]-100

h <- ggplot(huron, aes(year))

h +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = level, ymax = level2), fill = "grey80") +
  geom_line(aes(y = level)) + geom_line(aes(y=level2))
```

will result in this Chart:
[image]

I'd like to fill the area, where (ymin > ymax), with a different colour  than where (ymin < ymax). In my real data I have export and import values. There, I'd like to color the area where export is higher than import green, where import is bigger than export I want the ribbon to be red.

Alternative: I'd like geom_ribbon to only fill the area, where ymax > ymin.

Does anybody know how this is done?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An option that doesn't require manually creating another column would be to do the logic within `aes(fill =` itself;

```
## fill dependent on level > level2
h + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = level, ymax = level2, fill = level > level2)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = level)) + geom_line(aes(y=level2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "green"), name="fill")
```

[image: filled conditional on level > level2]

Or, if you only want to fill based on that condition being true,

```
## fill dependent on level > level2, no fill otherwise
h + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = level, ymax = level2, fill = ifelse(level > level2, TRUE, NA))) +
  geom_line(aes(y = level)) + geom_line(aes(y=level2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("green"), name="fill")
```

[image: filled conditional on level > level2, not otherwise]

I assume the lack of interpolated fill seems to have something to do with the `ggplot2` version, as I get the same thing happening with @beetroot's code

```
## @beetroot's answer
huron$id <- 1:nrow(huron)
huron$group <- ifelse(huron$id <= 50, "A", "B") 

h <- ggplot(huron, aes(year))
h +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = level, ymax = level2, fill = group)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = level)) + geom_line(aes(y = level2))
```

[image: @beetroot's answer]

I get @ManuK's image output when running that code without logic in `aes(fill =`.

Comment: Wow this is great, thank you very much! Its exactly what I wanted as I can basically put a condition into 'fill ='. However I'll leave my change request open as it's not perfect: the fill can't be applied perfectly to the point of intersection. (This time no problem for me) Also, I still think the filling logic in ggplot2 needs to be changed.

Comment: Super helpful! Is there any way to achieve the same result with data in long format? So for instance with your data set up as: Year, Level (1 or 2), Value. I can get as far as: h + geom_line(aes(y=Value, group=Level) but I can't figure out how to add in the geom_ribbon() layer with this structure.

Comment: Not easily, I don't think. `ggplot2` expects columns, so you need to have a column to use as the `ymin` and `ymax` values. It's fairly straightforward to `tidyr::spread()` your long data into the required format though.

Comment: Ah alright – I was hoping I could avoid changing the format, but so be it. Thanks Jono!

Answer (score 8):

You can add a grouping variable to the data that you can use to specify the fill colour. However, the problem is the point where the two lines intersect as it needs to be included in both groups to prevent any gaps.

So first find this row..

```
huron[huron$level == huron$level2,]

> huron[huron$level == huron$level2,]
     year  level level2 
50   1924 577.79 577.79 
...
```

And add it to the data once more:

```
huron <- rbind(huron, huron[huron$year == 1924,])
huron <- huron[order(huron$year),]
```

Then add an id column based on the row index, and set the groups based on the row number of the year 1924:

```
huron$id <- 1:nrow(huron)
huron$group <- ifelse(huron$id <= 50, "A", "B") 

h <- ggplot(huron, aes(year))
h +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = level, ymax = level2, fill = group)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = level)) + geom_line(aes(y = level2))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, this works. In my usecase however it's not very usable because of the following problems:
1. I'd like to add multiple ribbons, so I would need to add quite a few 'workaround' columns. 2. The points where the lines meet aren't really visible in the data, thus I'd need to calculate these points and add into the database (twice). I've hoped for an easy solution, but it seems to be more complicated than an easy conditional-fill. :-)

Comment: @ManuK yes, especially the 2. problem is difficult to solve as far as I know and unfortunately I can't help you there at the moment. But maybe someone else will come up with another answer? Maybe [this](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/10/22/ggplot2-two-color-xy-area-combo-chart/) blog post gives you some ideas

Comment: I submitted the problem as a feature request to the ggplot2 github. I hope it will be implemented in a future release of ggplot2 [link to request](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1642)

Answer (score 7):

Getting around the issue I had with non-interpolated `fill`, you can use two (or `n`) ribbons

```
h <- ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(data = huron[huron$level >= huron$level2, ], aes(x = year, ymin = level, ymax = level2), fill="green") +
  geom_ribbon(data = huron[huron$level <= huron$level2, ], aes(x = year, ymin = level, ymax = level2), fill="red") +
  geom_line(data = huron, aes(x = year, y = level)) + 
  geom_line(data = huron, aes(x = year, y = level2))
h
```

[image: Fill is interpolated now]

Any condition you use in `aes(fill =` is going to coerce it to a factor, so it seems to only apply where the data actually is. I don't think this is a `ggplot2` bug, I think this is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227527/ggplot2-cannot-color-area-between-intersecting-lines-using-geom-ribbon?noredirect=1&lq=1) solved question there is a pretty neat way to solve this, which only requires the use of the `pmin()` function within the `geom_ribbon()`:

```
h +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = level,  ymax = pmin(level, level2), fill = "lower")) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = level2, ymax = pmin(level, level2), fill = "higher")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = level)) + geom_line(aes(y=level2))
```

[image: geom_ribbon]

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions didnt work for me as I had data with multiple intersections, this is what helped me.

This solution introduces a function that interpolates the dataset slightly, namely the intersections are interpolated with the `fill_data_gaps()` function:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# finds the intercept between two lines.
# note that C and D are fixed to the same x coords as A and B
find_intercept <- function(x1, x2, y1, y2, l1, l2) {
  d <- (x1 - x2) * ((l1 - l2) - (y1 - y2))
  
  a <- (x1*y2 - x2*y1)
  b <- (x1*l2 - x2*l1)
  
  px <- (a*(x1 - x2) - (x1 - x2)*b) / d
  py <- (a*(l1 - l2) - (y1 - y2)*b) / d
  list(x = px, y = py)
}

fill_data_gaps <- function(data, xvar, yvar, levelvar) {
  xv <- deparse(substitute(xvar))
  yv <- deparse(substitute(yvar))
  lv <- deparse(substitute(levelvar))
  
  data <- data %>% arrange({{xvar}}) # not needed?
  
  grp <- ifelse(data[[yv]] >= data[[lv]], "up", "down")
  
  sp <- split(data, cumsum(grp != lag(grp, default = "")))
  
  # calculate the intersections
  its <- lapply(seq_len(length(sp) - 1), function(i) {
    lst <- sp[[i]] %>% slice(n())
    nxt <- sp[[i + 1]] %>% slice(1)
    it <- find_intercept(x1 = lst[[xv]], x2 = nxt[[xv]],
                         y1 = lst[[yv]], y2 = nxt[[yv]],
                         l1 = lst[[lv]], l2 = nxt[[lv]])
    it[[lv]] <- it[["y"]]
    setNames(as_tibble(it), c(xv, yv, lv))
  })
  
  # insert the intersections at the correct values
  for (i in seq_len(length(sp))) {
    dir <- ifelse(mean(sp[[i]][[yv]]) > mean(sp[[i]][[lv]]), "up", "down")
    if (i > 1) sp[[i]] <- bind_rows(its[[i - 1]], sp[[i]]) # earlier interpolation
    if (i < length(sp)) sp[[i]] <- bind_rows(sp[[i]], its[[i]]) # next interpolation
    sp[[i]] <- sp[[i]] %>% mutate(.dir = dir)
  }
  # combine the values again
  bind_rows(sp)
}
```

Create some fake data

```r
N <- 10
set.seed(1235)

data <- tibble(
  year = 2000:(2000 + N),
  value = c(100, 100 + cumsum(rnorm(N))),
  level = c(100, 100 + cumsum(rnorm(N)))
)
data
#> # A tibble: 11 x 3
#>     year value level
#>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  2000 100   100  
#>  2  2001  99.3  99.1
#>  3  2002  98.0 100. 
#>  4  2003  99.0  99.4
#>  5  2004  99.1  99.0
#>  6  2005  99.2  98.1
#>  7  2006 101.   98.6
#>  8  2007 101.   99.2
#>  9  2008 102.   98.7
#> 10  2009 103.   98.1
#> 11  2010 103.   98.4

data2 <- fill_data_gaps(data, year, value, level)
data2
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#>     year value level .dir 
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#>  1 2000  100   100   up   
#>  2 2001   99.3  99.1 up   
#>  3 2001.  99.2  99.2 up   
#>  4 2001.  99.2  99.2 down 
#>  5 2002   98.0 100.  down 
#>  6 2003   99.0  99.4 down 
#>  7 2004.  99.1  99.1 down 
#>  8 2004.  99.1  99.1 up   
#>  9 2004   99.1  99.0 up   
#> 10 2005   99.2  98.1 up   
#> 11 2006  101.   98.6 up   
#> 12 2007  101.   99.2 up   
#> 13 2008  102.   98.7 up   
#> 14 2009  103.   98.1 up   
#> 15 2010  103.   98.4 up
```

Note that we have more rows with interpolated values (eg rows 3, 4, 7, 8).

Then we can use `ggplot2::geom_ribbon()` as usual/expected.

```r
ggplot(data2, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = level, ymax = value, fill = .dir)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = level), linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Dir", values = c("up" = "green", "down" = "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: If I recall rightly, someone made a package that manages this. Anyone recall what it is? I'm looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78117978/geom-smooth-line-different-color-based-on-y-intercept-line?noredirect=1#comment137719551_78117978 where it would help.

Comment: It was `ggbraid`: https://github.com/nsgrantham/ggbraid